# Code won't change when choosing a different opinion in select list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selector list with two opinions inside. I want to run a block of code if the first is selected, and a different code if the other is selected. I have used if else for this.

So far I have assigned each select opinion a value, and the code works, but won't change if I choose opinion two...

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  window.onload = checkGender;

function checkGender() {
  document.getElementById("btnFortune").onclick = chooseFortune;
}

function chooseFortune() {

  if (document.getElementById("male").value === "1") {

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var formulaMale = name.length * document.getElementById("age").value - document.getElementById("height").value;


    document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = formulaMale;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = "Test";
  }
} <
/script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Spådom</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <body>
    <h1>Fortune teller</h1>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Tell me your name.."><br/>
    <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Your age.."><br/>
    <input type="number" id="height" placeholder="And height..(in cm)"><br/>
    <select>
 <option id="male" value="1">Male</option>
 <option id="female" value="2">Female</option>
</select><br/>
    <button type="button" id="btnFortune">Tell me my fortune!</button>
    <p id="fortuneTxt"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Spådom</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
 window.onload = checkGender;

 function checkGender() {
  document.getElementById("btnFortune").onclick = chooseFortune;
 }

 function chooseFortune() {

  if (document.getElementById("male").value === "1") {

   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var formulaMale = name.length * document.getElementById("age").value - document.getElementById("height").value;


  document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = formulaMale;

  }

  else {
   document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = "Test";
  }
 }
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Fortune teller</h1>


<style type="text/css">
 
</style>


<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Tell me your name.."><br/>
<input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Your age.."><br/>
<input type="number" id="height" placeholder="And height..(in cm)"><br/>
<select>
 <option id="male" value="1">Male</option>
 <option id="female" value="2">Female</option>
</select><br/>
<button type="button" id="btnFortune">Tell me my fortune!</button>
<p id="fortuneTxt"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the gender like shown below!

First assign an ID to the `select` element like.

```
<select id="gender">
    <option id="male" value="1">Male</option>
    <option id="female" value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

Then using the below javascript lines you can get the selected value!

```
  var select = document.getElementById("gender");
  if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value === "1") {
      console.log("Male");
  }else{
      console.log("Female");
  }
```

```js
  window.onload = checkGender;

function checkGender() {
  document.getElementById("btnFortune").onclick = chooseFortune;
}

function chooseFortune() {
  var select = document.getElementById("gender");
  if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value === "1") {

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var formulaMale = name.length * document.getElementById("age").value - document.getElementById("height").value;


    document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = formulaMale;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = "Test";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Spådom</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <body>
    <h1>Fortune teller</h1>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Tell me your name.."><br/>
    <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Your age.."><br/>
    <input type="number" id="height" placeholder="And height..(in cm)"><br/>
    <select id="gender">
 <option id="male" value="1">Male</option>
 <option id="female" value="2">Female</option>
</select><br/>
    <button type="button" id="btnFortune">Tell me my fortune!</button>
    <p id="fortuneTxt"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Spådom</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = checkGender;

    function checkGender() {
      document.getElementById("btnFortune").onclick = chooseFortune;
    }

    function chooseFortune() {

      var select = document.getElementById("gender");
      if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value === "1") {

        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var formulaMale = name.length * document.getElementById("age").value - document.getElementById("height").value;


        document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = formulaMale;

      } else {
        document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = "Test";
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Fortune teller</h1>


  <style type="text/css">

  </style>


  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Tell me your name.."><br/>
  <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Your age.."><br/>
  <input type="number" id="height" placeholder="And height..(in cm)"><br/>
  <select id="gender">
 <option id="male" value="1">Male</option>
 <option id="female" value="2">Female</option>
</select><br/>
  <button type="button" id="btnFortune">Tell me my fortune!</button>
  <p id="fortuneTxt"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange="chooseFortune()"` to call the function when the select box selected item is changed. And give id to `select` not `option`

```js
function chooseFortune() {

  if (document.getElementById("gender").value == "1") {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var formulaMale = name.length * document.getElementById("age").value - document.getElementById("height").value;
    document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = formulaMale;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("fortuneTxt").innerHTML = "Test";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fortune teller</h1>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Tell me your name.."><br/>
<input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Your age.."><br/>
<input type="number" id="height" placeholder="And height..(in cm)"><br/>
<select id="gender" onchange="chooseFortune()">
 <option value="1">Male</option>
 <option value="2">Female</option>
</select><br/>
<button type="button" id="btnFortune">Tell me my fortune!</button>
<p id="fortuneTxt"></p>
```